# Java's Wildcard

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

i was trying to compile this and could not figure out few things. I will appriciate your help.

1. What is the meaning of`List<? extends Exception> lst = new ArrayList<Exception>();`
   why this line can be  compield? Because for example this isnt compile

```
List<NullPointerException> lst2 = new ArrayList<Exception>();
```

2. Lets assume that we have the code as follows:

```
public class examsQ<S> {

    
    public void f3(Collection<? extends S> c, List<S> l ) {
        c = l;
    } 
}
```

I cant understand why this code compiles. For example, is c is a collection of subclass of S how can it point to l? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow.  One question : those bits of code above, did you (1) copy / paste directly from your IDE, or (2) type them into the question.   I’m guessing you typed then, because neither would compile.  please ALWAYS copy/paste code, never type them.

Comment: hi ! sorry about that! fixed it!:)

Comment: `List<? extends Exception> lst` means that `lst` will hold list of *some specific* subtype of Exception (including Exception itself). This means we can assign to it `new ArrayList<Exception>` but also `new ArrayList<NullPointerException>`, `new ArrayList<IOException>`, etc. We don't know which *specific* type of Exception `lst` will handle, so we can't *add* new elements *via* `lst` (so `lst.add(new NullPointerException())` is not legal since `lst` may at that time hold `List<IOException>`. BUT we can *read* from it any value and treat it as Exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java has *call-site variance*, which means the caller gets to decide which direction the subclass relationship goes in generic relationships.

Let's assume we've got a class `Parent` and a subclass called `Child`. Generally speaking, it's not safe to treat a `List<Child>` as a `List<Parent>` or vice versa. If we try to cast a `List<Child>` to a `List<Parent>` then someone could come along and `.add` something that isn't a `Child` to it, breaking our list. Conversely, if we try to cast a `List<Parent>` to a `List<Child>` and it contains some things that *aren't* `Child` instances, we're equally out of luck.

*However*, each cast still provides us with a guarantee. If I have a `List<Child>`, then I know that every element of that list is a `Child` and hence (by the 'is-a' relationship established by subclasses) every element of that list is a `Parent`. So if we *only* intend to read from the list and never to write to it, it's safe to take a `List<Child>` and treat it as a read-only version of `List<Parent>`. That's exactly what `List<? extends Parent>` is. It says "I've got a list, it contains some subclass of `Parent` and I don't know which one. It's safe to *get* elements from this list and cast them up to `Parent` since, no matter what class the `?` represents, it's always safe to assume it's a `Parent` subclass. So an argument of type `List<? extends Parent>` can accept a `List<Parent>` or a `List<Child>` or a list of any subtype of `Parent`. But we can't add elements to a `List<? extends Parent>` because we don't know what type the `?` is, so we can never safely supply an argument to `List.add`. This is called a *covariant* relationship, where it's safe to consider a list of a subclass to be a list of the superclass for these purposes.

The converse relationship is called *contravariant*. It's the exact same idea, but it's a little harder to understand sometimes. In Java, we would write it as `List<? super Child>`. A `List<? super Child>` is a list of some *supertype* of `Child`. That `?` could be `Parent` or it could be `Object` or it could be some interface that `Child` happens to implement, but it has to be a supertype of `Child`. Now, we can never safely get elements from this list, since we have no idea what the type is. It's not `Child`, since the list could be a `List<Parent>` and could contain non-`Child` instances. However, we can add elements to the list. Whatever the `?` is, it's a supertype of `Child`, so we can always safely add `Child` instances to `List<? super Child>`, since the argument to `add` can just be quietly upcast to the correct type.

Going back to your examples,

```
List<? extends Exception> lst = new ArrayList<Exception>();
```

The left-hand type is a list of *some subtype* of `Exception`. Notably, `ArrayList<Exception>` implements `List<Exception>` and, since `Exception` is (trivially) a subtype of itself, `List<Exception>` is a valid `List<? extends Exception>`.

```
List<NullPointerException> lst2 = new ArrayList<Exception>();
```

Here, `ArrayList<Exception>` is still a subtype of `List<Exception>`, but `List<Exception>` is incompatible with `List<NullPointerException>`, because in the absence of any variance annotations (`extends` or `super`), all generic arguments are assumed to be *invariant* (except arrays, but that's a whole other can of unsound worms). We could have written

```
List<? super NullPointerException> lst2 = new ArrayList<Exception>();
```

and gotten a *write-only* list of `NullPointerException`, or we could have written

```
List<? extends Exception> lst2 = new ArrayList<NullPointerException>();
```

and gotten a *read-only* list of `Exception`. But we have to specify which we want. Likewise,

```
public void f3(Collection<? extends S> c, List<S> l) {
    c = l;
}
```

`List<S>` implements `Collection<S>`, and `S` is (again, trivially) a subtype of `S`, so we have `Collection<S>` compatible with `Collection<? extends S>`, hence the assignment compiles.

More useful reading material on when you want `extends` vs. `super`: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)