# ArrayList of Objects That Inherit from Parent Classes in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, extends

I have a class, `controlBase`, that is inherited by other child classes. How can I make a list of any of these child classes?

I have tried:

```java
private ArrayList<? extends controlBase> controllers = new ArrayList();
```

However, this doesn't allow *any* classes to be added to it. With the above example, this throws an error:

```java
public <T extends controlBase> void registerController(Class<T> c) {
    controllers.add(c);
}
```

An error is also thrown when I execute:

```java
controllers.add(new controlBase());
```

or

```java
controllers.add(new joystick()); // Joystick is a child-class of controlBase
```

This does not allow any classes to be added, even in the first example where it explicitly states that the class extends `controlBase`.

How can I make this arrayList be only of objects that extend the `controlBase` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the point of the call-site variance annotations. `? extends ControlBase` is meant to imply that data can be safely *read* from the container as `ControlBase` but that *nothing* can be written to it. See [my answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72758195/javas-wildcard/72758313#72758313) for more details about when you would *want* to use this syntax, or [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) for a summary of the general rules.

In your case, you want, quite simply, `ArrayList<ControlBase>`. Every `Joystick` *is a* `ControlBase`, by the rules of inheritance, so you can add any subclass to that `ArrayList` whenever you like.

Comment: `Class<T>` is a *class*, not an instance. `ControlBase` *itself* (as in, the idea of a control base) is an instance of `Class<ControlBase>`. In your first example, you're looking for `void registerController(T c)`. You probably won't see `Class<T>` until you get into some more advanced Java, as it's only used for reflection.